# SSH key on unsubscribed RHEL

Tags: ssh, rhel

I want to use ssh keys for authentication but my base server is with unsubscribed RHEL .

Though target severs are running subscribed RHEL . But my script needs to run on my base server.

Comment: Don’t use all capital letters in a title. (Excepted if you are really sure your question is far more important than all others).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, try `ssh-keygen`. This will create a key pair. Get the `id_rsa.pub` and add it on the server (target) side in a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (In a directory of the account you try to connect to). You can concatenate multiple keys in this file (if you have multiple clients).